# angular fixed-table-header.js is not align properly after sorting

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fixed-header-tables

I am using fixed-table-header.min.js, which is working fine on default, whereas after perming my sorting(server side sorting) the grid alignment get lost. i mean header and the tbody is not inline. any help ?

```
    <table>
      <thead fix-head>
        <tr>
          <th width="20px">Col 1</th>
          <th width="80px">Col 2</th>
          <th width="20%">Col 3</th>
          <th width="30%">Col 4</th>
          <th width="20%">Col 5</th>
          <th width="10%">Col 6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>value 1111</td>
          <td>value 2222</td>
          <td>value 3333</td>
          <td>value 44444</td>
          <td>value 55555</td>
          <td>value 66666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>value 1111</td>
          <td>value 2222</td>
          <td>value 3333</td>
          <td>value 44444</td>
          <td>value 55555</td>
          <td>value 66666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>value 1111</td>
          <td>value 2222</td>
          <td>value 3333</td>
          <td>value 44444</td>
          <td>value 55555</td>
          <td>value 66666</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>                    


<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Consider `datatables.net` - alternatively, look at this - pure css https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code you can easy to freeze your table row

```
  table thead {
      position: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: The table header width will not align with tbody td width,,, get some inconsistent on that if we have position:fixed. more over all my th and td are dynamically rending..